# Novel trilogy about electromagnetic ogres/goblins

Tags: story-identification, books

Recently I remembered a trilogy of novels I read maybe around 2013/2015 which are about a boy who discovers there exists some ogres/goblins/(I can't remember exactly the term) in the world, and they are split into 7 categories: one for each type of electromagnetic waves, so Gamma, X-Ray, IR, UV, etc...

He soon discovers he is one of them, but decides to help humans instead of following his own nature. In the second and third volumes, the world descends into chaos because of those monsters.

I read it in my native tongue (French) but I am pretty sure it was translated from English. I can't remember the name or the author, but I do remember the cover of the first volume: half the face of the protagonist who has bright blue hair.

Comment: "*Forged in rage and sorrow, a dark witch’s spell travels down her ancestral line to Violet Levina. Enchanted with the power of the entire Electromagnetic spectrum—microwaves, gamma rays, radio waves, Violet is cursed with limitless energy and the obligation to destroy an insidious creature composed of dark matter.*" - [probably not your story](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/27909628-fire-s-field), but I dropped a link just in case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, after a while I finally found the book by chance in the bookshelf in my old room, and it is no wonder why nobody answered, as it's a French novel:

*[The Strange Case of Jack Spark](http://victordixen.com/the-strange-case-of-jack-spark)*, by Victor Dixen (Original title : *Le cas Jack Spark*).

[image: Front cover of Le Cas Jack Spark]

> Jack Spark, a New-York teenager suffering from allergies and insomnia, is sent by his parents to the Redrock teenage boot camp, in the middle of the Rocky Mountains. This experience is about to disrupt his life to a point he could never have imagined.
>
> The rehabilitation methods used in Redrock by the spooky doctor Krampus have unusual effects on Jack, transforming his body and mind into something that is not entirely human.
>
> Jack soon realizes that Redrock is ruled by hundreds of creatures which he thought only belonged to the darkest fairy tales... and they are now claiming him as one of their own.

Comment: Thank you for returning to answer.

Comment: How did you find it? Was it a matter of seeing it on your shelf? Remembering the title in a dream? Finally finding the right set of search keywords?

Comment: I haven't found a cover for the first book with blue hair, although he does sport it for the next two books.

Comment: That's the exact book I own anyway, I guess I was mixing up with the cover of another book.
And yes I found it in my old bookshelf, I edited the answer.